# Iframe horizontal scroll is always hidden

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, iframe

My Iframe's horizontal scroll is always hidden but I would like to see it the scroll-x on my web page. I do not understand why the scroll-x never appears ? The scroll-y does appear but not the horizontal one.

Any suggestion ?

```
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
                <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
                    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item"   src="http://fr.lichess.org/training/29058" style="overflow-x: scroll;"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Overflowing in Related Styles / Classes**

After examining the CSS for the target of your `<iframe>`, it looks like the `<body>` appears to explicitly restrict this through the [`overflow-x`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow-x) property as seen below :

[image]

Additionally, the `embed-responsive` class that is targeting your `<iframe>` will also restrict this as it's [`overflow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow) property is hidden entirely :

[image]

**A Solution (if you can adjust your inner-page)**

However, if you explicitly remove the `overflow-x: scroll;` property on your `<iframe>` it should work as expected and set the `overflow-x` property on your inner page to `auto` :

```
/* Adjust this in your inner page (common.css, line 906) */
body {
    /* Other styles omitted for brevity */
    overflow-x: auto;
}
```

Then you should see it working as expected :

[image]

Comment: then if the target of my iframe restrict the overflow-x property I can not do anything to solve the problem ?

Comment: Do you have access to adjusting the `overflow-x` property of the target page? This would be the easiest solution as the `<body>` style of that inner page is explicitly causing the `overflow-x` property to be ignored.

Comment: Access to the overflow-x of the target page ? I'm not the webmaster of that chess website. So I can't have access to the css properties of that chess website. I hope I understand what you're saying ... ?

Comment: I didn't know if you had access to it or not. If you don't, then you are going to be quite limited in what you will be able to adjust on the site. The style that is causing the problem would need to be overridden to avoid this, which if it isn't on the same domain as your site, you'll run into a cross-origin error if you tried to set it via Javascript (which is basically a very hackish way of trying to resolve it).

Comment: ok then I thank you so much for having explained me all the problem. I've choosen another target website to embed a chess game on my website. I accept your answer have a good evening.

Answer (score 0):

`.embed-responsive` has the `overflow` property set to `hidden`.

`.embed-responsive-item` has no `overflow` property.

Try this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-push-4">
        <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3" style="overflow-x: scroll;">
             <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://fr.lichess.org/training/29058"></iframe>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
```